# I'm using react-native-photo-upload library to upload profile pic but it's throwing build failed error

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

The libary I'm using is `yarn add react-native-photo-upload` from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-photo-upload
and it's throwing the following error:

```
**/home/haseeb/Desktop/RN/myProject/node_modules/react-native-image-picker/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v26/values-v26.xml:15:21-54: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.

/home/haseeb/Desktop/RN/myProject/node_modules/react-native-image-picker/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v26/values-v26.xml:15: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.
:react-native-image-picker:processReleaseResources FAILED

**FAILURE**: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-image-picker:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 5.653 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html**
```

i tried `android.enableAapt2=false` in gradle.properties of react-native-image-picker but no gain...same error

plz help to resolve it!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your problem looks like it will be difficult to reproduce without clarifying the question a little. Please could you try to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?

Comment: What is the sdk, build tools and support library version you have..

Comment: my gradle version:distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5.1-all.zip

Comment: uildToolsVersion = "26.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"

Comment: dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to follow the instructions of the library, after running `yarn add react-native-photo-upload`
, you need to make sure to link the package and build the project again:

```
react-native link react-native-image-picker
react-native link react-native-image-resizer
react-native link react-native-fs
```

After that, you can go to `yourProject/android/settings.gradle` and verify if all modules have been added. It may look like:

```
include ':module-name'
project(':module-name').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, 
'../node_modules/module-name/android')
```

You may also go to `yourProject/android/app/build.gradle` to check if the modules are present on the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':module-name')
}
```

Comment: '../node_modules/react-native-fs/android')
include ':react-native-image-resizer'
project(':react-native-image-resizer').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-resizer/android')
include ':react-native-image-picker'
project(':react-native-image-picker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker/android')
include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')

include ':app'

Comment: modules have been added moreover also present in build,gradle